# Замена главного изображения при наведении на любую из тумб ниже

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Как сделать или каким плагином можно воспользоваться чтобы решить задачу.

Есть серия картинок (6шт). Первая показывается большим размером, остальные пять картинок, маленькими тумбами, стоят под большой. Как сделать чтобы при наведении мышью на любую из мелких тумб, большая картинка менялась на изображение из тумбы?

Comment: Тумба это уменьшенная версия картинки. все картинки одинакового размера. верхняя показывается в своем оригинальном размере, нижние с помощью css сжаты до размера тумбы. При нажатии на тумбу ничего происходить не должно. Только при наведении. Увы кода пока нет, думал может есть jquery готовые плагины

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Буквально, ваше тз можно исполнить на css:

```css
.gallery {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 70px;
}
.item {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}
.item .preview {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.item.first .preview {
  display: block;
}
.item:hover .preview {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="item first">
      <img src="//placehold.it/32x32/ff0000" alt="" class="thumb">
      <img src="//placehold.it/64x64/ff0000" alt="" class="preview">
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <img src="//placehold.it/32x32/00ff00" alt="" class="thumb">
      <img src="//placehold.it/64x64/00ff00" alt="" class="preview">
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <img src="//placehold.it/32x32/0000ff" alt="" class="thumb">
      <img src="//placehold.it/64x64/0000ff" alt="" class="preview">
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <img src="//placehold.it/32x32/ffff00" alt="" class="thumb">
      <img src="//placehold.it/64x64/ffff00" alt="" class="preview">
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <img src="//placehold.it/32x32/00ffff" alt="" class="thumb">
      <img src="//placehold.it/64x64/00ffff" alt="" class="preview">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

суть в следующем, - большая картинка позиционируется абсолютно относительно блока "галереи" помещается в блок вместе с маленькой, при наведении на этот блок, большую показываем.

Comment: супер, спасибо. Прям в точку что мне нужно)

Comment: @Regent да я что-то вообще их не считал :) можно и 5 сделать, у последней цвет все равно дурацкий.

Comment: да тут можно хоть 5, хоть 6, хоть 10 тумб поставить )

Comment: @eicto нет, я про другое. Изначально в вопросе было сказано так: одна большая сверху и 5 **других** внизу. То есть всего 6 картинок - одна текущая большая и 5 других маленьких. Описание подробной механики смены картинок при наведении на маленькую я в комментариях к вопросу так и не получил. Возможно, просто было плохо описана именно такая задача. Раз автора устраивает решение задачи, то я лишь впустую потратил время на попытки понять первоначальную задачу, и просто остановимся на этом ответе. В конце концов, решение такой задачи без JS весьма занятно для меня.

Comment: если картинку из под мыши выносить наверх это будет неюзабельно совсем, ясно же что хочется чего-то простого и всё таки работающего, от того и такое решение. Вам нужно просто граммарнаци немного придавить в себе, т.к. он начинает вам расшифровывать текст по правилам, а правда в том, что по правилам мало кто говорит, а язык  - протокол с очень сильной коррекцией ошибок. Т.е. если вам кажется, что кто-то сказал белый шум, это всего лишь кажется, и ваш инспектор слишком строг.

Comment: @eicto люди разные бывают - мало ли что кому в голову придёт. Вопрос всё равно неточно составлен. Вы угадали с его интерпретацией, я - нет. Если бы автор хотя бы HTML-код набросал, то мне бы и спорить не пришлось.

Comment: не пойму что неточного в вопросе. Вопрос составлен максимально дотошно. и чтобы код @eicto был в точь что мне надо было, просто надо убрать одну строчку кода, вот эту `<img src="//placehold.it/32x32/ff0000" alt="" class="thumb">` @Regent вам все равно большое спасибо :)

Comment: :) да понятно, я про что речь веду - язык, особенно русский, вообще неточная штука, она спецом так составлена, чтобы на fussy logic можно было обмениваться инфой. Я сейчас живу в стране, где люди не могут по буквам сказать номер машины, т.к. у них в языке согласные не так важны как тона,  - у одних это читается как R а у других как Z :)